# getRange(),setFormulas doesn't want to work

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following code and when I run it I get the right number of items in sheetFormulas (4), and the array values look correctly formed.

However, I get an error right after the sheetFormulas Browser.msgBox pops up, indicating the getRange().setFormulas line has an issue, but I can't see what it is.

```
function test(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var testingTarget = ss.getSheetByName("Testing");
    var sheetFormulas = new Array();
    for (l=0;l<10;l++) {
        sheetRowCount = l + 2;
        var monthlyTotalCompanyCosts = '=F' + sheetRowCount + '/$F$29*$I$14';
        var monthlyTotalCompanyCostsPerEa = '=IFERROR(H' + sheetRowCount + '/C' + sheetRowCount + ')';
        var monthlyMargin = '=D' + sheetRowCount + '-F' + sheetRowCount;
        var monthlyMarginPctg = '=IFERROR(J' + sheetRowCount + '/D' + sheetRowCount + ')';
        sheetFormulas.push(monthlyTotalCompanyCosts,monthlyTotalCompanyCostsPerEa,monthlyMargin,monthlyMarginPctg);
    Browser.msgBox("sheetFormulas.length is: " + sheetFormulas.length);
    Browser.msgBox("sheetFormulas is: " + sheetFormulas);
    testingTarget.getRange(sheetRowCount,8,1,4).setFormulas(sheetFormulas);
    sheetFormulas = [];
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated,

Phil

Answer (score 0):

First, sheetFormulas has to be a 2D array. So try doing

```
/* Notice the [] around sheetFormulas */
testingTarget.getRange(sheetRowCount,8,1,4).setFormulas([sheetFormulas]);
```

If you still see other problems, then put your code inside a try{}catch{} block and print out the exception in the catch block.

I also suggest that you print out the formula using Logger.log() before setting it on the spreadsheet.